# Scrollview does not scroll when keyboard appears

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have a few EditTexts in my RelativeLayout, and a button aligned at the bottom of it. When the keyboard pops up, I want my layout to resize (therefore, I'm using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize") and also want it to be scrollable, because in smaller screens resizing it isn't enough.

The problem is I can't get it to scroll at all!

I do need the Button to stay at the bottom of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <!-- some hidden RelativeLayouts, filling the whole screen -->

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/form_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true" android:layout_above="@+id/ok_btn">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#99000000" android:visibility="visible">

            <View
            android:id="@+id/shade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/logradouro1"
            android:background="#FFF" android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"/>

            <!-- some visible EditTexts and TextViews here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/ok_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" android:background="@color/verdeBotao" android:text="Cadastrar"
            android:textColor="#FFF" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Below are 2 screenshots to illustrate what is happening. Please notice that I can't scroll when the keyboard is up.
Thanks!

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

i am posting something similar to your ui. take a RelativeLayout for the button at the bottom. set gravity to bottom and your button view should  **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true**"

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/m_table_menu" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layuserdetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            Yourviewss......i guess edittexts 

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

//scrollable Button layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/m_table_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/laysharepost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

//replace textview with buttonview.. 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/share_tvcommentdone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="POST"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Aren't you using a ScrollView? I think I should use it to handle small screens

Comment: I guess my problem is somehow related to setting `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in a view within a ScrollView

Comment: whydont you take  a linearlayout as a rootelement. give it a try.